# How can I catch a golden bee?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

The Bee Guy says he'll give me an even bigger reward for a Golden Bee. Is there a specific place these bees appear or a certain thing I need to do? Is the reward more rupees or an item?

Comment: I found 2 gold bees simoultaneously under lorule castle that long patch of dying grass. If that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Golden Bee appears randomly (1/50 chance). Your best bet is to just keep slamming into trees and cutting grass and bushes until it appears. The Golden Bee is differentiated by a golden glow surrounding it, as well as being stronger and tougher than a regular bee.

If you don't want to catch one, you can purchase one from several vendors in Lorule.

- Skull Woods: The Mysterious Man in the cave will sell you one for 888 Rupees.
- Various regular vendors in Lorule sell one for 9999 Rupees.

I don't recommend buying one, as the cost dwarfs the reward:

> The Bee Guy will pay 300 Rupees for each Golden Bee, as well as give you the `Bee Badge` for the first Golden Bee you turn in. The badge makes all bees friendly to you and they will attack enemies (just as if you let the bee out of your bottle!).

Comment: I found one in Kakariko village beside the milk shop immediately after he requested the Golden Bee.

Comment: Although it's a necessary item to get one of the streetpass achievements, so if you've already beaten the game and have R9999 to burn (as you probably do if you're achievement-grinding) it's not a terrible option.

Answer (score 2):

Later on in the **dark world** in NorthWestern edge of the map (**Skull Woods**) you will be able to buy it for **880 rupees** from the guy in the cave.

Another mention is that you can catch the golden bee in **Kakariko village**. After obtaining the net from the bee guy you just go cutting grass and bushes around.

> You will get an **item (bee badge)**, which makes bees attack enemies onscreen when you find them.

[Discussion on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/711412-the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-between-worlds/67905976)

Comment: Sadly, you can only buy this one once. If you want the StreetPass achievement you'll have to either find one or spend R9999.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find one. but its VERY rare so if you cant find one buy it from the guy in skull woods.It will cost 888$ not that much if you have a lot of money.